# Abitrary Shape Of Sets Error when defining Partition Slicers

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008

I'm trying to adapt the concept of designing Slicers within my Cube for associated Partitions. This is a practice that I typically have avoided because of familiarity with the Auto-Slice concept where creating Slicers are treated more so as options as opposed to proper design.

However, this one error is becoming a total annoyance and I am considering going back to avoiding their use if no one can provide a reasonable solution to the infamous, "An arbitrary shape of the sets is not allowed in the current context" error.

I am receiving this error when attempting to process my cube with slicers that use my Calendar Date Hierarchy. Here is an example of one of the Partition Slicers:

```
{[Calendar Dates].[Calendar Dates].[Calendar Year].&[2007].&[QUARTER NUMBER 2].&[APRIL].&[2007-04-01T00:00:00]
,[Calendar Dates].[Calendar Dates].[Calendar Year].&[2007].&[QUARTER NUMBER 2].&[APRIL].&[2007-04-02T00:00:00]
,[Calendar Dates].[Calendar Dates].[Calendar Year].&[2007].&[QUARTER NUMBER 2].&[APRIL].&[2007-04-03T00:00:00]
,[Calendar Dates].[Calendar Dates].[Calendar Year].&[2007].&[QUARTER NUMBER 2].&[APRIL].&[2007-04-04T00:00:00]
,[Calendar Dates].[Calendar Dates].[Calendar Year].&[2007].&[QUARTER NUMBER 2].&[APRIL].&[2007-04-05T00:00:00]
,[Calendar Dates].[Calendar Dates].[Calendar Year].&[2007].&[QUARTER NUMBER 2].&[APRIL].&[2007-04-06T00:00:00]
,[Calendar Dates].[Calendar Dates].[Calendar Year].&[2007].&[QUARTER NUMBER 2].&[APRIL].&[2007-04-07T00:00:00]}
```

My first greivance is that I have to manually specify every Member of the set because the use of the range (:) operator is prohibited. The size of the Cube I am maintaining is enormous and just creating the number of Partitions required are an extreme task in itself so not having the use of the range operator is just simply a poor restriction IMHO. I saw that there was a request on MSConnect to correct this design issue but the last response I noted was that it was too late for SQL2008 R2. No mention of intention to address it later releases though.

Please see: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339861/automatically-resolve-arbitrary-shaped-sets-to-subcubes

Getting past my gripe session, I cannot see where or why my defined set creates an arbitrary shape. Furthermore, looking at examples as to what constitutes an Arbitrary Set Of Shapes, I cannot see any correlation to suggest that my set falls into that category.

What do I need to do to circumvent the problem and avoid the annoying error?

Any advice or suggestions are GREATLY welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.

In all examples I reviewed as to what can potentially cause this error there was an attempt to define a Slice on a Partition that required a crossJoin across different dimensions which caused the error, "An arbitrary shape of the sets is not allowed in the current context".

Although my defined set doesn't use an explicit cross join across different dimensions, the elements of the set are a product of a User-Defined Hierarchy and so there is an implicit Cross Join required to produce the Slice.

To alleviate the Implicit Cross Join, I re-created the members of my set to be at the base attribute level and voila!

So the revised set is now:

```
{[Calendar Dates].[Dates].&[2007-04-01T00:00:00]
,[Calendar Dates].[Dates].&[2007-04-02T00:00:00]
,[Calendar Dates].[Dates].&[2007-04-03T00:00:00]
,[Calendar Dates].[Dates].&[2007-04-04T00:00:00]
,[Calendar Dates].[Dates].&[2007-04-05T00:00:00]
,[Calendar Dates].[Dates].&[2007-04-06T00:00:00]
,[Calendar Dates].[Dates].&[2007-04-07T00:00:00]}
```

And the error is resolved.